# AdSense lots of requests slowing down site

Tags: performance, adsense, pagespeed

Working on optimizing this site (lanogkreditt.com) for speed. Half the loading now seems to come from Google AdSense. Is it normal that AdSense makes so many requests and slows the site down this much?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately yes.

Even Google’s PageSpeed Insights detect problems with browser caching and image optimizing for AdSense.
Turn off AdSense and try to optimize the site for speed as much as possible…

Also, don’t show ads from other URL, if no ads available (ad unit options).